# Сравнение итераторов STL

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/)
{
    using lisst = std::list<int>;
    lisst mylist;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        mylist.push_back(i + (i*i));
    }
    for(int & x : mylist) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    lisst::iterator b_it = mylist.begin();
    lisst::iterator e_it = mylist.end();
    --e_it;
    while(b_it != e_it) // ??????????
    {
        std::swap(*b_it, *e_it);
        ++b_it;
        if(b_it == e_it) break; // ??????????
        --e_it;
    }
    for(int & x : mylist) std::cout << x << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: почему в цикле while проверка на равенство работает некорректно. Добавление условия if исправляет ситуацию ?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb ну да, не подумал. Но всё равно = тут бесполезно. Оба итератора сразу сдвигаются. Я просто привык уже лист поверх вектора самопальный юзать вот и не подумал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы двигаете оба итератора одновременно. При четном количестве элементов они могут "разминуться". Ваш `if` как раз этот случай и проверяет.

А вообще, раз уж вы подключили `algorithm`, то пользуйтесь им:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/)
{
    using lisst = std::list<int>;
    lisst mylist;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        mylist.push_back(i + (i*i));
    }

    std::copy(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));    
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::reverse(mylist.begin(), mylist.end());
    std::copy(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: про std::reverse известно, надо без него. Спасибо.

Comment: @Sakton, ну раз уж известно, то в будущем можете [подсматривать](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/?kw=reverse) примерную реализацию

Comment: Спасибо разобрался